# Buildozer throwing "The command was not found or was not executable"

Tags: android, python, kivy, buildozer

After installing all the necessary libraries, when I run

```
buildozer android debug
```

in my Kivy app's directory, it throws the following error

```
pexpect.exceptions.ExceptionPexpect: The command was not found or was not executable: /home/ethan/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools.save/android.
```

I've tried using Kivy's own VM clone, and I get the exact same error. I've tried compiling the example apps, same issue.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There should be no `tools.save` sub folder, you could try symlink

```
.../.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools
```

to

```
.../.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk-20/tools.save
```

here is a [ref about symbolic link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/)